# Problema ao gerar Migration com EF Core e .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, oracle

Estou com o seguinte problema ao gerar a seguinte migration >
PM> Add-Migration CriadoTabelaTarefa -Verbose -Context TarefaContext

**Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'TarefaContext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[PMQ.GerenciamentoTarefas.Infra.Data.Context.TarefaContext]' while attempting to activate 'PMQ.GerenciamentoTarefas.Infra.Data.Context.TarefaContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728**

Assim está o meu código,
Dbcontext:

```
    public class TarefaContext : DbContext
    {
        public TarefaContext(DbContextOptions<TarefaContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Tarefa> Tarefas { get; set; }
    }
```

E assim está minha Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();

        services.AddDbContext<TarefaContext>(options => options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        MediatorInjection.AddMediator(services);
        //DependencyInjection.AddServices(services);
    }

    public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();
    }
}
```

OBS: Meu Context está em um projeto de Infra.Data e claro meu Startup no projeto da API.

Alguém já passou por isso, poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score -3):

Consegui resolver atualizando a biblioteca Pomelo para versão 8.0.0-beta.2

```
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="8.0.0-beta.2" />
```

Answer (score -4):

Uma pergunta, o comando da Migration, você está rodando a partir de qual projeto? Está rodando na raiz da solution do projeto, ou dentro do projeto de infraestrutura na qual contém o Context?

1. Validar se você tem uma classe de configuração para cada entidade sua, isto é uma classe na qual dizemos para o Entity que ele terá propriedades e chaves primárias e relações.
   Segue o exemplo abaixo, de um diretório chamado Configurations dentro do projeto de Infraestrutura, com uma classe chamada `UserConfiguration.cs`

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(u => u.UUID);

        builder.Property(u => u.Name);
        builder.Property(u => u.Email);
        builder.Property(u => u.Password);
        builder.Property(u => u.CreatedAt);
    }
}
```

2. Validar se você tem um diretório chamado `Migrations` no seu projeto de infraestrutura, ou, você pode adicionar ao comando da migration, este argumento `--output-dir Migrations`
3. Validar se no seu TarefaContext, contém este trecho de código abaixo:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

Caso todas as opções estejam válidas, siga para a leitura abaixo.

Você pode rodar o comando pelo terminal da seguinte forma. Vá para a raiz da sua solution, e execute o comando abaixo, lembrando para que você troque os path dos projetos para os seus respectivos projetos. Coloquei um exemplo de um código meu para ficar mais fácil o entendimento do comando.

```
dotnet ef migrations add --project Visualizesse.Infrastructure/Visualizesse.Infrastructure.csproj --startup-project Visualizesse.API/Visualizesse.API.csproj --context Visualizesse.Infrastructure.DatabaseContext
```

Caso, não dê certo, adicione o `--verbose` para termos um stack trace mais completo.

Uma possível causa de erro ao rodar o comando acima, pode ser que apareça para baixar o NuGet Package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`, e ele deve ser instalado no projeto da API, digo isso pois quando rodei o comando acima, ele mostrou que faltava este NuGet, ao baixar, rodei novamente o comando e funcionou, eu espero que para você funcione também.